# bad connector on board

Tags: cpu, motherboard

I have a question, I recently got a board and it would not power on but would turn the power supply on when power button was pressed, I traced the issue to the 8 pin cpu connector on the board and then found out the old owner had plugged a 6 pin pcie connector into it prior to it's not turning on. Now it acts just like the 8 pin connector is not plugged in even when it is. The rest of the board is functional. My question is, is there any way to fix the 8 pin power connector on the board, or any way to replace it?

Comment: *is there any way to fix the 8 pin power connector on the board, or any way to replace it?* - Anything for a price can be fixed, but unless you have access to generic ICBs and pretty advanced soldering skills, you are better off either replacing the motherboard or taking it to a professional.

Comment: There is a way to replace it, but damaged connector is likely to be visibly damaged if it actually is damaged. If there is not visible damage to the connector, the damage is likely elsewhere. If there is visible damage to the connector, then yes, it is possible to replace it. The process isn't terribly complicated, but it requires some care and soldering skill at the very least, and runs the risk of more damage if done improperly. What @Ramhound says is correct and I would second his recommendation of taking the device to a professional for testing and possibly repair.